# Not loading multiple tabs of the same website

Tags: asp.net, iis

Scenario:

IIS Version 10.0.14393.0 installed.
Net framework 4.6.1 installed.
Windows 10

We are having an issue when opening multiple tabs of the same website hosted in our server.

If we open 3+ tabs at the same time, the site wont load. The exact same package is installed on another server and working properly.

We have cross checked the application pool(4.0 integrated) with the working one, and the site configuration too and they are the same.

We even changed the connection string of the website to connect to the db of the site working and it also fails.

This happens when connecting from another machine, and also when opening the website on the server itself.

Any help?

Comment: Disable DB interaction and try again? Have you checked the IIS logs? Is there an error being reported in the browser? Is there a particular HTTP status error code being returned?

Comment: We have checked the IIS logs and the information there is normal. There is no error reported in the browser, and when the tab doesn´t load all the requests remain in "pending". When we close one of the other tabs, all of the request will finish and the page will load correctly

Comment: Is this specific to a particular browser? Have you tried narrowing it down in a VS debugging session?

Comment: It is not specific to a particular browser, I tried with Edge, Firefox and Chrome. We will try it, thank you